Батник для удаления изображений
Суть:
Я скачиваю видео, загружаю в софт который разбивает видео на кадры в формате jpg. На выходе я получаю папку с множеством кадров.
Задача:
Мне не нужны все кадры а только 6 случайных кадров с папки.
Можно ли командой bat удалить все изображения с папки и оставить 6 случайных? Не первые или последние или по порядку а именно случайные! Случайные нужны для разнообразия кадров.
Прошу помощи в реализации.

Генерация случайного числа  от  MIN до MAX: SET /A R=MIN+(MAX-MIN+1)*%random%/32768 вот отсюда - https://forum.script-coding.com/viewtopic.php?id=3372
